# Webpack 2 extracted stylesheet doesn't load until I manually change the file in chrome console (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, webpack-2

I am trying to integrate Webpack 2 into the build process of an AngularJS 1.6 application. I am actually trying to extract the CSS from the generated HTML using the **ExtractTextPlugin**.

The problem is when I extract the CSS file using the **ExtractTextPlugin**:
[The CSS is extracted into an external file styles.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yhKJ.png) but it isn't loaded on the page unless I make a change on the CSS file in the chrome console (Even just adding a space) [Here I added a space and the CSS was loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeEa5.png).

**I don't understand why isn't the CSS loaded on first run and why does it load when I make any small change.**

### More Details:

I have been following this tutorial on SurviveJS and other tutorials on the survivejs website and main Webpack website.

This is my current Webpack Configuration file:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const ngAnnotatePlugin = require('ng-annotate-webpack-plugin');
const FaviconsWebpackPlugin = require('favicons-webpack-plugin')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const fs = require('fs');
const gracefulFs = require('graceful-fs');
const TypedocWebpackPlugin = require('typedoc-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const posthtml = require('posthtml');

gracefulFs.gracefulify(fs);

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: './src/index.ts'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
        publicPath: '../'
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'], {
            root: __dirname + "/../",
            verbose: true
        }),
        new ngAnnotatePlugin({
            add: true
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            'window.jquery': 'jquery'
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            minChunks: function (module) {
                return module.context
                    && (module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1 || module.context.indexOf('bower_components') !== -1);
            }
        }),
        //CommonChunksPlugin will now extract all the common modules from vendor and main bundles
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'manifest'
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            inject: 'body',
            hash: true
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
            context: 'raw/',
            from: '**/*',
        }]),
        new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
            cssProcessor: cssnano,
            cssProcessorOptions: { 
                discardComments: {
                    removeAll: true 
                }
            },
            canPrint: true
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/i,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader'],
                    use: ['css-loader', 'less-loader']
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    { 
                        loader: 'html-loader', 
                        options: { 
                            minimize: true 
                        } 
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg|ico)$/i,
                loaders: [
                    'file-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                        query: {
                            mozjpeg: {
                                progressive: true,
                            },
                            gifsicle: {
                                interlaced: false,
                            },
                            optipng: {
                                optimizationLevel: 7,
                            },
                            pngquant: {
                                quality: '75-90',
                                speed: 3,
                            },
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                enforce: "pre",
                loader: 'tslint-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /^((?!\.spec\.ts).)*.ts$/,
                enforce: "post",
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src"), "node_modules", "bower_components"]
    }
};
```

Comment: may be loaded with wrong mime type. is there some warning in your console?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, I received this in the console: `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://localhost:8070/styles.css?c5c78d63fb639f815a8f".` . Do you have any idea why would this be happening? And even when sending the wrong MIME type, is the expeted behavior for the CSS not to load until changed manually? Thanks

Comment: how you're calling the css file from html?

Comment: It was being injected by webpack as `<link href="../styles.css?d2d3bfafb4e5864e99c4" rel="stylesheet">` without the type attribute. I tried manually adding type="text/css" in the generated html file, however I get the same error as before.

Comment: try removing `rel=stylesheet`. That might be the problem and let me know if it worked or not

Comment: I tried removing `rel=stylesheet`, I don't get the error in the console `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet ...`, however, I get the same behavior: the CSS isn't loading on page.

Comment: do both. remove rel and add type

Comment: I also tried adding `type="text/css"` after removing `rel=stylesheet`, however, it is the same thing: no error but css not loading

Comment: After looking further, it appears that when I remove `rel=stylesheet`, the file isn't even loaded in the Chrome console > Sources tab at all, even when `type="text/css"` is added.

Comment: are you sure it's not loaded? probably rel is the issue

Comment: @i-- , thanks for your help, however, I don't understand, the whole behavior is very weird, when I remove stylesheet, this is how the sources tab looks like [Sources Tab - Google Chrome Console](http://imgur.com/a/HTxfH), no css at all loaded unlike when I have `rel=stylesheet` [Sources Tab - Google Chrome Console](http://imgur.com/a/Hj9a4), even when I have `type="text/css"`